# AWS Elemental MediaLive output Dolby Digital audio channels order

Tags: amazon-web-services, audio, video-streaming, aws-media-live, dolby

I have trouble finding the answer to my question which is:
In AWS Elemental MediaLive service I have a channel with input and output (to MediaPackage) already set. In one of the output groups the stream is setup with audio codec set to AC3, and in the section "Codec Configuration" there is a field "Coding Mode", which in my case is a dropdown with the following values to pick from:

- CODING_MODE_1_0,
- CODING_MODE_1_1,
- CODING_MODE_2_0,
- CODING_MODE_3_2_LFE

Hovering over "*info*" button next to that field states: "Dolby Digital coding mode. Determines the number of channels. DEFAULT "CODING_MODE_2_0".

I have chosen **CODING_MODE_3_2_LFE** and my question is in what order are the channels in that option?

Which standard is it following?
Is it

**L R C LFE Ls Rs** - **SMPTE**

 or

**L C R Ls Rs LFE**  - **film** ?

I did try to look it up on AWS documentation pages to no avail, it only states possible options, not the standard it follows. In Elemental Server pages (different service) you can find hints that it's actually film order, but can anyone confirm it?

I also did try to use Live Chat to ask the same question, but it's permanently "currently offline or busy[...]"

Comment: for the AC3 Codec,  coding mode  CODING_MODE_3_2_LFE
outputs the channels in SMPTE order which is L R C LFE Ls Rs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the AC3 Codec, coding mode CODING_MODE_3_2_LFE outputs the channels in SMPTE order which is L R C LFE Ls Rs.